# Excluding external directory from clang-tidy check using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, clang-tidy, juce

I am building a C++ project with the JUCE framework using CMake. I want to set up CMake to run clang-tidy on builds, and I have set up my CMakeLists.txt to look like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

project(myProject VERSION 1.0.0)


set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(JUCE CONFIG REQUIRED)

juce_add_gui_app(myProject 
    VERSION 1.0.0
    PRODUCT_NAME myProject)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES
    "src/SourceFile1.cpp"
    "src/SourceFile2.cpp"
    "src/Header.h"
)

target_sources(myProject PRIVATE ${SRC_FILES})

set_target_properties(myProject PROPERTIES
    CXX_CLANG_TIDY "clang-tidy;-header-filter=^(!?${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}\\Builds|${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH})"
)

target_link_libraries(myProject
    PRIVATE
        juce::juce_audio_basics
        juce::juce_audio_devices
        juce::juce_audio_formats
        juce::juce_audio_processors
        juce::juce_audio_utils
        juce::juce_core
        juce::juce_data_structures
        juce::juce_dsp
        juce::juce_events
        juce::juce_graphics
        juce::juce_gui_basics
        juce::juce_gui_extra
    PUBLIC
        juce::juce_recommended_config_flags
        juce::juce_recommended_lto_flags
        juce::juce_recommended_warning_flags
)

juce_generate_juce_header(myProject)
```

I also have a .clang-tidy file:

```
---
Checks: >
  -*
# All my checks here...

WarningsAsErrors: '*'

CheckOptions:
# Options here...
```

When running CMake I set the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the path of my JUCE modules. The problem is that these files in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` are always included in the clang-tidy check and triggers a huge amount of warnings and errors. As you can see I've tried filtering them out using the `--header-filter` but to no effect. I think one problem might be that the JUCE modules are not built library files that is linked, but rather source files that's pulled in on build. How do I go about solving this?